# is it possible to set different height and width for a dialog in Angular material Design Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am working in an angular 5 application ,In this application for login purpose I have a Angular Material Design popup .

I have the following process in the dialog screen .

**checking user mail if it's new signup form will be enabled or password field will be enabled.**

So Initially I have the dialog height and width as **100 * 100** for the **email input**

If the user not exist the **signup** form will be enabled for that I want to set the height and width as **300*100**

If user already exists then **password** field  will be enabled along with email input for that i want to set **200 * 100**

I am new to this so I could not find a solution also searched on SO can't solve it .

```
 myAccountClick(event) {

        const dialogScreen = this.dialog.open(MyaccountComponent,{height:'100px',width:'100px'});

    }
```

can anyone help me to solve this .

Comment: can't you initially check those conditions, and then in each cases pop up 3 different dialog?

Comment: I already think about having 3 dialog  ,but I want to know that if there is any other way to do that ...@ViranMalaka

Comment: Or when the condition changes, just close the dialog and reopen the dialog with different size and prefilled data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within your dialog's component you can inject `MatDialogRef` and call its `updateSize` method to change the height/width according to your needs.

Check an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-dialog-resize)